# Maven: Limiting dependencies on client jar built via assembly

Tags: maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I am building a *server* jar that contains all of my classes, and a *client* jar that has only a tiny subset of those classes.

I use the `maven-jar-plugin` to build my *server* jar, and the `maven-assembly-plugin` to build my *client* jar. This produces the two jars that I need.

However, the client jar has the same dependencies as the server jar, even though it doesn't have a lot of the classes that require those jars. When someone adds the client jar as a dependency, as part of a war, it downloads dozens of unneeded jars.

Is there a way I can trim this jar dependency list for the *client* jar? That is, without setting up multiple Maven project?

Comment: Maven doesn't really have a good way to determine that excluding classes can make some dependencies not needed though. At runtime, all bets could be off. It sounds like you should have 3 modules: a common module, one module building your server JAR and one module building your client JAR...

Comment: @David W. Just to confirm, are these client and server jars generated from different modules? *..When someone adds the client jar as a dependency, as part of a war, it downloads dozens of unneeded jars...* - Just to debug, can you try `<groupId>some.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>clientArtifact</artifactId>
            <version>some.Version</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>` and build to find the needed ones

Comment: @nullpointer Nope. These are generated by a single module. All the source for the server is there, so I make a `foo-1.0-server.jar` (setting `<classifier>` in my `maven-jar-plugin`. Then, I create an assembly that produces `foo-1.0-client.jar`. Quick and simple. Plus, this was an already existing project, and I didn't want to dig through the code trying to untangle it.

Comment: @Tunaki Yeah, I should have three modules with interwoven dependencies.  See my addendum for a further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this out:

You can't limit dependencies via the assembly to build jars with different classifiers. If this is a problem, you should make a modularized project with the separate *client* and *server* jars as their own modules. It's more complex, but you have more control over it.